# using markov and chebyshev inequalities in the same problem

Tags: probability, inequality, random-variables

The problem states as following: Let's say the width in the fabrication process of an industrial metal piece has a mean of 10 and an standard deviation of 1. Find the probability for when the width is less than 6 or greater than 14.

I know this can be solved using both the Markov and Chebyshev inequalities, but I'm not pretty sure about how to apply them. Do I use Chebyshev to find out the upper bounds and Markov to do so with the lower bounds or viceversa?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you apply any one of them to find one of the bounds?  Then you can do the question as the distribution is symmetric about the mean.  Both inequalities are essentially the same.

Comment: Chebyshev will do it.